# Bundling and minification is sending old styles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I was followed this article to setup bundling and minification, http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification.

I thought it was working great, until I updated some css, but I kept getting the old style. I am working in firefox, I have cleared my cache, restarted my browser, restarted IIS, and even restarted my computer, and nothing is working.

When I turn off bundling and minification

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

The new styles show up and the page looks as it should. Turn bundling and minification back on and I get the old styles again. Also, whenever I rebuild or change one of the css files, there is is a new chache busting token. So you would think that it is sending different content, but I still get the old stuff. I even added a test class to one of the css files, then downloaded the minified css file, but the test class I added is not there.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: Use Firebug or F12 tools to see what's going on. Can you post a repro someplace? I wrote that tutorial and I can't repro your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't I feel like the bonehead. Apparently I am working too many hours. I had a style.min.css file that the optimizer was using, but I was making changes to style.css.  I even knew that is what the optimizer did, but I...  Well no excuses. It was a brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

Follow my instructions under **Debugging Bundled and Minified JavaScript** to figure out what you're doing wrong.

> > rebuild or change one of the css files, there is is a new chache busting token
> >     Verify you are using RC and not beta. Rebuilding will not change the cache busting token, only a change will.